# Remote Desktop Connection with VM not working

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, vmware

i am trying to establish a RDC to a VM in VMWare. I can ping the Machine and RDC is enabled on the VM. The Interface is bridged, but it still is not working.
Any idea, what i could have missed?

Edit:
The Reason was, that i used the IP instead of the Machines Name. Don´t know why, but now i will always try to connect with IP AND Machine Name :/

Comment: You mean RDC in Windows Guest?

Comment: You should not have to disable any firewalls. Are you trying to connect via an IP address or a PC name - have you tried both? In the target machine have you selected to allow connections from any PC or only those using network level authentication?

Comment: It works now =) I don´t know why, but the Problem was, that i tried to establish the connection via IP. When i used the Machines Name, the connection worked :/

Comment: @BJ292 put that as an answer, I think OP will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Disable firewall on guest machine.

Make sure you have password set for the local admin account on the Guest machine.

Comment: They are disabled on both machines and admin passwords are set.

Comment: Have you tried telnet "Guest machine hostname" 3389?
If you get blinking cursor - then the connection is Ok.

Are you connecting via hostname or IP-address? Try both variants.

Comment: The problem was the IP Adress, using the machines name fixed the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Check the firewall on both the host and the VM and turn it off. There is another way to check the connectivity - just share a folder on the VM and access it on the host machine.

Comment: The firewalls are turned of on both machines. And the networkshare works from the host and the machine i want to connect with.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to disable any firewalls. Are you trying to connect via an IP address or a PC name - have you tried both? In the target machine have you selected to allow connections from any PC or only those using network level authentication?